# react.js: events instead of passing handler in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React.js, the parent component passes the handler to update its state via props. In deeply nested components, this can become pretty messy. Is there a way to do this via pub-sub - the parent listens for an event, and executes the handler when it gets fired by the child?

PS: got the idea from Ractive.js (http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components#events).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking up the flux architecture that facebook uses with their react apps. They use a type of "pub/sub" in singleton stores, and use actions to update the data stores. When an update happens, the store notifies all subscribed controls to update. I've used this setup for a few personal projects, and with great success it has reduced this style of 'mass prop passing' that looks so ugly.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html

Comment: Absolutely agree with this answer, flux is the way to go once things start getting very nested and complex.  Loving it at the moment personally.

Comment: You should mention other popular flux-based state handling solutions such as Redux